# Can Object.defineProperty only modify the setter?

Tags: javascript

I want my object to have a field that when read returns the fields value, and when a val is written to the field, I want to modify the val before writing it. My current code is this:

```
function Cat(lives) {
    var self = this;

    var privateLives;
    Object.defineProperty(self, 'publicLives', {
        get: function() {return privateLives;},
        set: function(val) {privateLives = 7 * val;}
    });
}
```

Is there a way to do this without making a private variable? Ideally I would simply have the setter be this:

```
function(val) {self.publicLives = 7 * val;}
```

but that causes an overflow as the setter calls itself. Is there some way to make so it just doesn't loop the setter (so only assignment outside the setter's scope calls the setter and assignment in the setter just does normal assignment)? If that's possible, I wouldn't need to explicitly define a getter either as the setter writes to a public field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible - a property can only be either a data property or an accessor property, not both. Of course you don't necessarily need to store the value in a private variable from your setter, you can use a different property or a property on a different object (like in @Oriol's proxy) as well. If you want to avoid private variables, "private" properties are the standard approach:

```
function Cat(lives) {
    this.publicLives = lives;
}
Object.defineProperty(Cat.prototype, 'publicLives', {
    get: function() {return this._privateLives;},
    set: function(val) { this._privateLives = 7 * val;}
});
```

But you can also do some tricky things and hide the "private variable" by using a constant getter function that is repeatedly redefined:

```
Object.defineProperty(Cat.prototype, 'publicLives', {
    set: function setter(val) {
        val *= 7;
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'publicLives', {
            get: function() { return val; }
            set: setter,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, an alternative would be using a [Proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) with a [[[Set]] trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set):

```js
function Cat(lives) {
  return new Proxy(this, {
    set: function(target, prop, val) {
      target[prop] = val;
      if (prop === 'publicLives') target[prop] *= 7;
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```